# Table name ignored in subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have 2 tables:

    `table1
    +-----------------+------------+--------+-------+-----------+---------    +
    | Field           | Type       | Null   | Key   |   Default | Extra       |
    |-----------------+------------+--------+-------+-----------+---------    |
    | id | binary(16) | NO     |       |    <null> |         |
    +-----------------+------------+--------+-------+-----------+---------+`

`table2
    +-----------------+------------+--------+-------+-----------+---------+
    | Field           | Type       | Null   | Key   |   Default | Extra   |
    |-----------------+------------+--------+-------+-----------+---------    |
    | id | binary(16) | NO     |       |    <null> |         |
    +-----------------+------------+--------+-------+-----------+---------+`

Why is this query working (and retrieving all records from table1)?

    `select * from table1 where id in (select table1.id from table2);`

If I do only this:

    `select table1.id from table2`

MySQL complains about unknown column.

Comment: table1 is reference in parent query and can be used in sub query

Comment: All the columns after SELECT should be present in the table(s) specified in FROM clause.

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid yes, but I expected an error or so, because in subquery I'm trying to select a field from the wrong table. Basically, my query is equivalent to "select * from table1 where id in (select table1.id)", which is valid.

Answer (score 0):

The table can be referenced as `table1` in the subquery because it has already been referenced as such in the outer query, unless a table has been referenced in an outer query, the reference is unavailable to subqueries, see this example:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (field CHAR(1));
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('A'), ('A'), ('A');

CREATE TABLE table2 (field CHAR(1));
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES ('A'), ('B');

# Works as table1 has been referenced in the query
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE field IN (SELECT table1.field FROM table2);

# Doesn't work as table1 now has the alias 'alias', so table1 is not available to reference by this name in the subquery
SELECT * FROM table1 AS alias WHERE field IN (SELECT table1.field FROM table2);

# Works as table1 now has the alias 'alias', so it can be referred to as such in the subquery
SELECT * FROM table1 AS alias WHERE field IN (SELECT alias.field FROM table2);
```

See the official docs [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/correlated-subqueries.html).

Regards,

James

Comment: I think I wasn't very clear in my example. What puzzles me is that if in subquery I select a field which does not exist, I still get results. For example: "select * from table1 where id in (select id from table_without_id)" will get all rows from table1. It's similar to "select * from table1 where id in (select id)"

Comment: The field id exists in both tables in your example, it is referenced correctly in your first query but not in the second, what leads you to think it doesn't exist?

Comment: As I said, my example was poor. I'm interested on what happens if I select a field from a table which does not exist. Thanks.